# Facebook Graph API Post Image

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post an image to Facebook using ASP.NET, it's not working and get these warnings.

Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed:
Inferred Property:
The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred  from
other tags.
Inferred Property:
The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred
from other tags.
Inferred Property:
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred
from other tags.

What does it mean with "explicitly provided"? And does someone have any good examples with publishing photos using ASP.net? Would be much appreciated!

And this is the parameters:

```
WebRequest(oAuthFacebook.Method.POST, 
"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed/access_token=" + oAuth.Token,
"http://www.test.com/Image.aspx?" + image;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you added your meta tags to your page

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="thumbnail_image" />
```

Explicitly provided means they have to be present on the page and if not an error is thrown

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me once, it's possible you have wrong `og:url` value.
I had same Open Graph Warnings, problem was I was working inside a "dev" folder for testing stuff (`http://example.com/dev/`) and the `og:url` meta-tag was set for the root folder (`http://example.com/`), so Facebook was looking for EVERYTHING in example.com/ instead of example.com/dev/

The Warnings went out when changed `og:url` to `example.com/dev/`

Answer (score -1):

Could you show us the code you are using in your header of your HTML?
And I suggest you use the Facebook URL Linter to test and debug since Facebook caches every URL the first time you try to share it: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Yes, I was using that to debug. Edited my question.